# NetBeans Code Completion is extremely slow for Java

Tags: java, netbeans

Im using NetBeans 7.0.1 on a Mac, Code completion for Java programming is extremely slow.
for example when I want to call a variable by start to typing its name it takes about 1 to 2 second for cc to pop up which is quite annoying in times of programming.
Is it a fixable issue?

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_* Update ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

I was trying settings in eclipse,
under : eclipse -> Preferences -> Java/Editor/Content Assist
there is an Option which you can define timing for cc popup, by default it is 200ms.
But for netBeans... !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans is a great IDE with many good features. I used to play with it, but moved to Eclipse because how slow it is.

Nowadays I use Intellij IDEA, which is faster and more stable than both Eclipse and Netbeans and has the best Maven integration IMHO.

Thanks.